# How to dynamically change JMS queue MDB pool size in WildFly 10

Tags: java, jms, wildfly, wildfly-10, activemq-artemis

I am working with WildFly 10.1 which ships with Artemis as the new JMS provider but I am unable to find how to dynamically change the number of consumer threads for a specific MDB.

I have a queue, and a message listener (MDB) consuming messages from the queue, now I want to dynamically control the maximum number of consumers threads the domain must start.

How can I do it using CLI?

Comment: May I ask why you want to configure this **dynamically**?

Comment: @RémiBantos Good question. The main reason is that pushing new versions for QA and Production is a pain within some customer's change processes. Whole process may take weeks, it must be manual, and executed by a 3rd party (no I am not kidding). I rather keep fine tuning flexible, so we are able to react quickly without dealing with the change department and get things done. I had good experiences in the past with this approach (using WebLogic's work managers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to do this configuration for a **specific** MDB you could firstly assign it to a dedicated pool. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116222/assign-a-pool-to-a-specific-stateless-bean-in-jboss-eap-6-1#answer-29214118).

Then to dynamically update your pool attributes you could take a look at [this article](http://planet.jboss.org/post/jboss_as_7_0_1_configuring_ejb3_pools) which describes how to configure or add ejb3 pools using jboss-cli or standalone.xml configuration. (with JBOSS 7, but it should not be so different with Wildfly 10)

The following jboss-cli command could then be used to modify your pool size dynamycally as it defaults to 20 for MDBs:

`/subsystem=ejb3/strict-max-bean-instance-pool=myPool:write-attribute(name=max-pool-size)`

Finally, it seems you also have to configure the 'maxSession' activation configuration property accordingly in your MDB. See [this thread](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/252757) and also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34030422/how-to-make-mdb-activation-spec-contextual-properties-configurable) for contextual configuration.

Comment: I was able to create the pool with max pool 50 and associate it with the MDB, but when I add 50 messages to queue only 15 are consumed at any time (previous default value). I used this command  to create the pool `/subsystem=ejb3/strict-max-bean-instance-pool=dummyPool/:add(max-pool-size=50,timeout=5,timeout-unit=MINUTES)` and used `@Pool` annotation and even `jboss-ejb3.xml` on the MDB, but the server still limits it to 15 instances. The `maxSession` activation is static. Do you know what it could be? I also tried restarting the server but it didn't work.

Comment: I also found [this article](http://www.mastertheboss.com/javaee/ejb-3/custom-pool-configuration-for-your-ejbs-on-jboss-as-7-wildfly), but following those steps didn't get my MDB to work using my custom pool.

Comment: Have you tried to set the maxSession activation configuration property? See this question and related answer for maxSession contextual configuration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34030422/how-to-make-mdb-activation-spec-contextual-properties-configurable